# Process each json record in json RDD using Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I need help with the below scenario:

I will get the data from Kafka in the following JSON format to spark streaming

```
{"id" : 1 , "data" : "AFGH00101219"}
{"id" : 2 , "data" : "AFGH00101215"}
{"id" : 2 , "data" : "AFGH00101216"}
{"id" : 3 , "data" : "AFGH00101218"}

val messages= KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

Now I want to process each JSON record from the messages and each record in turn returns set of records. Please give me some ideas to do the below task.

```
val output = messages.map(row =>
{
//here I will get each json record. My doubt is how to extract id and data 
//filed values from row and store it into variables.
//Here I need to decode the data filed value which is in hexa decimal format 
//to decimal format.
}
```

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Instead of using a StringDecoder, you could implement your own that actually parses the JSON to objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) or any JSON parsing library, I had used Google GSON as below to parse the JSON data that I received in spark streaming.

```
// loop each RDD 
lines.foreachRDD(rawRDD => {
    val rdd = rawRDD.filter(!_.isEmpty)
      .map(row => {
        val jobj = new Gson().fromJson(row, classOf[JsonObject])
        val id = jobj.getAsJsonObject("id").getAsString
        val data = jobj.getAsJsonObject("data").getAsString
        // Do something with id and data
      })
  })
```

The other way is to create a Dataframe from the received RDD

```
lines.foreachRDD(rawRDD => {
  val rdd = rawRDD.filter(!_.isEmpty)
  val df = spark.read.json(rdd)
  df.show(false)
  })
```

This creates a dataframe from rdd as below, No you can use id and data for any other transformation/operation.

```
+------------+---+
|data        |id |
+------------+---+
|AFGH00101219|1  |
|AFGH00101215|2  |
|AFGH00101216|2  |
|AFGH00101218|3  |
+------------+---+
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ideally, you should not make a new Gson deserializer for every row

Comment: @cricket_007 Write our own parser? What if we want to remove some of the element from json.

Comment: @cricket_007 does it improve the performance with a custom parser, I have used GSON on my project, so should definitely use own, if it improves.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. You extend Kafka's `StringDecoder`, or implement your own that converts String or ByteArray records to Java objects or `JSONObjects`. Spark has a *built-in* JSON parser, so I don't understand why you would even use Gson to begin with

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have few doubts for above replies. Do we need to use GSON or not. If not, can I approach Data Frame concept. But if I follow data frame, how will I iterate each record from the json like cursor in RDBMS. Please let me know.

Comment: You can go with the dataframe to do opetation with the data you can use   any operation like map, foreach, filter and many more